# Aggregating anonymous types using lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to print out a list of phone numbers (\n for each number) in a format {type}:{number}. So from a list of 2 numbers I would print out:

```
 Home: 111-111-1111
 Cell: 222-222-2222
```

So far I can select into an anonymous type but when I go to aggregate it is leterally printing out the whole anonymous type on the screen looking exactly like below:

```
 new { phoneType = Home + ": ", phoneNumber = 111-111-1111 }
```

Should I even be using aggregate?
This is what I'm working with:

```
  PhoneNumbers.Select(x => new { phoneType = x.PhoneType, phoneNumber = x.PhoneNumber1 }).Aggregate(
                (p, x) => new { phoneType = p.phoneType + ": ", x.phoneNumber });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the phone numbers as strings, you can create that string in a `Select` call:

```
var x = PhoneNumbers.Select(x => string.Format("{0}: {1}", x.PhoneType, x.PhoneNumber));
```

Your Aggregate call is basically a bug (assuming it even compiles) because you're combining the "current" phone number with the previous phone type.  It's also unnecessary for combining the phone numbers as text because of existing string methods:

```
var phoneNumberStrings = PhoneNumbers.Select(x => string.Format("{0}: {1}", x.PhoneType, x.PhoneNumber));
var text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, phoneNumberStrings);
```

Comment: Missing a call to actually execute the query, such as ToList, but overall good answer. He doesn't need the aggregate and even if he wants the object and not the string he just needs a call to execute the query, not an aggregation function

Comment: @BoredBlazer:  Not sure when you commented but `string.Join` will enumerate what it's given.

Comment: It was before you added the aggregate explanation. I'm assuming he was trying to use aggregate to execute the query or something so I didn't want him to repeat that mistake.

Comment: Yes I ended up doing what Timothy Shields did below, but that is basically what you said as well and you were the first to respond. Thanks for the help, I had a gut feeling aggregate wasn't the answer.

Answer (score 2):

While you could do this with `IEnumerable<string>.Aggregate`, I feel it's cleaner if you just use `string.Join`. Someone reading your code will be able to more easily get the meaning out if they see "join these strings with newline."

```
string.Join(
    Environment.NewLine,
    PhoneNumbers.Select(x =>
        string.Format("{0}: {1}", x.PhoneType, x.PhoneNumber));
```